# Error while running Eclipse RCP application from command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin which I wanted to run from command line without starting up eclipse. I achieved this using OSGi command :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
  -XstartOnFirstThread
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
  -Xms40m
  -Xmx512m
  -Declipse.ignoreApp=false
  -Dosgi.noShutdown=true    
  -Declipse.pde.launch=true
  -Dfile.encoding=MacRoman
  "-Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/aneeshmohan/Movies/eclipse Indigo/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.7.1.v20110802_r371/jdi.jar" 
  -classpath "/Users/aneeshmohan/Movies/eclipse Indigo/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar"
  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main
  -product org.talend.rcp.branding.tos.product 
  -data /Users/aneeshmohan/Desktop/MyWorkspace/../runtime-NewTalendCofiguration 
  -configuration file:/Users/aneeshmohan/Desktop/MyWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/NewTalendCofiguration/ 
  -dev file:/Users/aneeshmohan/Desktop/MyWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/NewTalendCofiguration/dev.properties 
  -os macosx 
  -ws cocoa 
  -arch x86_64 
  -nl en_US 
  -consoleLog 
  -console 
  -nosplash 
  --disableLoginDialog
```

This worked fine without issues. 
I now copied my eclipse and the workspace to another machine and made necessary changes in the paths but when I run it , I get the `osgi` console but end up getting the error :

```
!MESSAGE Error loading bundle datas.  Recalculating cache.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getExtensionFiles(BaseStorage.java:1163)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.addExtensionContent(BaseStorage.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.processFrameworkExtension(BaseStorage.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.processExtension(BaseStorage.java:1026)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.readBundleDatas(BaseStorage.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getInstalledBundles(BaseStorage.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getInstalledBundles(BaseAdaptor.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this error ?

Comment: What release of Eclipse is this?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: I see you are trying to use Windows paths staring your stuff on Mac. You use spaces and quotes in the paths. First I would try to use "safe" paths without spaces.